# Replication issue between child and parent Active Directory domain

Tags: active-directory

I have a lab that contains the ACME domain which ACME-DC2 and ACME-DC3.  It has a child domain called LAB with LAB-DC1.  I made some infrastructure changes to my environment that broke Active Directory DNS for a while. Replication between my ACME domain to the LAB domain appears to be broken:

```
 Starting test: Replications
        [Replications Check,LAB-DC1] A recent replication attempt failed:
           From ACME-DC2 to LAB-DC1
           Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=ACME,DC=local
           The replication generated an error (1256):
           The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
           The failure occurred at 2022-01-14 13:54:35.
           The last success occurred at 2019-05-03 19:45:51.
           20747 failures have occurred since the last success.
        REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
        ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
        Source ACME-DC2
        Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
        This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.
        [Replications Check,LAB-DC1] A recent replication attempt failed:
           From ACME-DC2 to LAB-DC1
           Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=ACME,DC=local
           The replication generated an error (5):
           Access is denied.
           The failure occurred at 2022-01-14 13:54:35.
           The last success occurred at 2019-05-03 19:45:51.
           20738 failures have occurred since the last success.
        [Replications Check,LAB-DC1] A recent replication attempt failed:
           From ACME-DC2 to LAB-DC1
           Naming Context: CN=Configuration,DC=ACME,DC=local
           The replication generated an error (5):
           Access is denied.
           The failure occurred at 2022-01-14 13:54:34.
           The last success occurred at 2019-05-03 19:45:51.
           20771 failures have occurred since the last success.
        REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
        ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
        Source ACME-DC2
        Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
        This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.
        [Replications Check,LAB-DC1] A recent replication attempt failed:
           From ACME-DC2 to LAB-DC1
           Naming Context: DC=ACME,DC=local
           The replication generated an error (1256):
           The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.
           The failure occurred at 2022-01-14 13:54:35.
           The last success occurred at 2019-05-03 20:16:26.
           39498 failures have occurred since the last success.
        REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING
        ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.
        Source ACME-DC2
        Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.
```

```
C:\Users\administrator.ACME> repadmin /replicate LAB-DC1 ACME-DC2 "DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=ACME,DC=local"
DsReplicaSync() failed with status 5 (0x5):
    Access is denied.
```

dcdiag reports:

```
         ......................... ACME-DC2 passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x8000001C
            Time Generated: 01/22/2022   18:09:57
            Event String:
            When generating a cross realm referral from domain LAB.ACME.L
verify the ticket. The ticket key version in the request was 15 and the avai
this error is a delay in replicating the keys. In order to remove this probl
 of keys to occur.
         ......................... ACME-DC2 passed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... ACME-DC2 passed test VerifyReferences
```

I've tried various things to fix it. The break was definitely longer than 180 days so I believe the LAB-DC has been tombstoned or vise-versa. I had seen some errors about this before. In an attempt to fix this, I set the "Strict Replication Consistency" to 0 in the Registry and re-ran the replication. This appears to have fixed some errors but I can't get around the "ACCESS DENIED".

I also had various references to ACME-DC1 (a dead DC from before) in the DNS data on the LAB-DC1. I went through and renamed all those to ACME-DC2.

Any idea how to fix this Access Denied error?

There is a second issue where the LAB domain has the old ACME-DC1 as the schema master and domain naming server. That DC existed in Sites and Services. I tried to delete it there but couldn't. I had to use ADSIEdit to delete it from the CN=Configuration area.

```
C:\Users\administrator.ACME>netdom query fsmo
Schema master               *** Warning: role owner is a deleted DC: CN=NTDS Settings\0ADEL:a1047a26-7404-43b1-8a6e-f260c2a73d14,CN=ACME-DC1\0ADEL:e307b4b3-3a49-4c03-a93f-9c0c8e
b45c10,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=ACME,DC=local
Domain naming master        *** Warning: role owner is a deleted DC: CN=NTDS Settings\0ADEL:a1047a26-7404-43b1-8a6e-f260c2a73d14,CN=ACME-DC1\0ADEL:e307b4b3-3a49-4c03-a93f-9c0c8e
b45c10,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=ACME,DC=local
PDC                         lab-dc1.lab.ACME.local
RID pool manager            lab-dc1.lab.ACME.local
Infrastructure master       lab-dc1.lab.ACME.local
```

I tried to correct this by using ADSIEdit and altering the fsmoRoleOwner (??) attribute and got WILL_NOT_PERFORM. I'm a little hesitant to try and seize a role.

I tried to also add a new domain controller to the LAB domain but it also errored out because of the invalid reference to ACME-DC1.

It's not the end of world if I have to trash the LAB domain but I'm hoping that I don't.

I also tried fixfsmo.ps1. It identified the errors and said it fixed them. When I try *netdom query fsmo though*, still shows the old entries.

***Edit***

I was able to fix this. I had several more problems.

The sysvol share on ACME-DC3 was missing. I was able to extend the maxofflinetimeindays days to past the error shown in the DFS replication event viewer and restart the DFS replication service. SYSVOL and NETLOGON re-appears on ACME-DC3. I reset the maxofflinetimeindays back to 60 afterwards.

I also found some more anomalous entries in my DNS from before I re-IPed the DCs. Fixed all of the them.

I manually added a NTDS connection between LAB-DC1 and NETOPIA-DC3. Not sure if this helped, but dcdiag was complaining that it was missing.

The secure channel between ACME-DC2 and ACME-DC3 was dead. I tried using netdom to repair but kept getting errors. I was finally able to use Active Directory Domains and Trusts to repair the trust relationship. This was a big step in fixing things. I had tried previously using PowerShell and netdom or nltest to repair the secure channel and couldn't. I finally just used this tool from each of the 3 DCs and both directions (child to parent and parent to child) and selected to validate the connection and repair. Eventually I got it to work.

Comment: Is the account a Domain Admin?

Comment: Most probably, the computer account (DC) password is expired (what you suspect to be tombstoned). By resetting the computer password, you may solve the repliaction issues you're facing. Can you try this simple procedure? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/ad-forest-recovery-reset-computer-account-dc